# how to map data in ReactJS hooks?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

I want to collect a JSON data by an API and render that as JSX to show but I'm new to react hooks and i see an error that say's data.map is not a function
can someone help me?

this is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ModalSubHeader from "../../styles/ModalSubHeader";
import CollectionHolder from "../../styles/CollectionHolder";
import {CollectionOption, CollectionOptionInner} from "../../styles/CollectionOption";
import CollectionIcon from "../../styles/CollectionIcon";
import CollectionIcons from "../../../../images/index";

function Collection(props) {

const [collectionList, setCollectionList] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://reg.my-waste.mobi/collections?project_id=556&district_id=556&zone_id=zone-z1250-z1261")
    .then(({data}) => {
        data = data.collection.types;
        const collections = data.map((number) =>
            <CollectionOption>
                <CollectionOptionInner>
                    <CollectionIcon src={CollectionIcons[number.iconicShape]} />
                    {number.title}
                </CollectionOptionInner>
            </CollectionOption>
        );

        setCollectionList(collections)
    })        

    
    console.log(CollectionIcons);
})

return(
    <div>
        <ModalSubHeader>What type of collection or event would you like to be reminded about?</ModalSubHeader>
        <CollectionHolder>
            {collectionList}
        </CollectionHolder>
    </div>
)
}

export default Collection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endpoint returns object not array, so you should rework it a bit Object.values(data.collection.types).map(collection => { .... })

Answer (score 0):

this code might work:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ModalSubHeader from "../../styles/ModalSubHeader";
import CollectionHolder from "../../styles/CollectionHolder";
import {CollectionOption, CollectionOptionInner} from "../../styles/CollectionOption";
import CollectionIcon from "../../styles/CollectionIcon";
import CollectionIcons from "../../../../images/index";

function Collection(props) {

const [collectionList, setCollectionList] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://reg.my-waste.mobi/collections?    project_id=556&district_id=556&zone_id=zone-z1250-z1261")
    .then(({data}) => {
        data = data.collection.types;
        setCollectionList(Object.values(data).map(item=>        ({title:item.title,iconicShape:item.iconicShape})))
    })        


    console.log(CollectionIcons);
})

return(
    <div>
        <ModalSubHeader>What type of collection or event would you like to be reminded                                 
              about?</ModalSubHeader>
        <CollectionHolder>
            {collectionList.map((number) =>
            <CollectionOption>
                    <CollectionOptionInner>
                    <CollectionIcon src={CollectionIcons[number.iconicShape]} />
                    {number.title}
                </CollectionOptionInner>
            </CollectionOption>
        )}
        </CollectionHolder>
    </div>
)
}

export default Collection;
```